# Is there a "structured catalog" of mathematical structures?

Tags: reference-request, online-resources

There are nice small overviews of classes of mathematical structures like [this overview of group-like structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)#Generalizations) that organize different classes of mathematical structures by the data and axioms that they have. Similarly here is a [list of possible added axioms to a topological space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_axiom), and here [the relation between inner-product spaces and so forth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space).

However, these are all small specialized lists. Is there a resource that attempts to catalog a vast number of mathematical objects (including relatively specialized ones) in an easily navigable format, such as a tree or DAG of increasingly restrictive signatures and axioms?

Comment: Simple answer: No, there is no such catalog.